# Clojure: Cycle through a collection while looping through another collection?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I have two collections `x` and `y`, both having different number of items. I want to loop through `x` and do something with a side-effect, while cycling through `y`. I don't want to repeat `y` while looping through `x`. Both `doseq` and `for` repeats `y`:

```
(for [x (range 5)
      y ["A" "B"]]
  [x y])
```

This produces `([0 "A"] [0 "B"] [1 "A"] [1 "B"] [2 "A"] [2 "B"] [3 "A"] [3 "B"] [4 "A"] [4 "B"])`.

What I want is something that will produce: `([0 "A"] [1 "B"] [2 "A"] [3 "B"] [4 "A"])`.

Background, I have lines from a file and `core.async` channels (say 5) and I want to put each line to the next channel in my collection, something like:

```
(defn load-data
  [file chans]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader file)]
    (go
      (doseq [l (line-seq rdr)
              ch chans]
        (>! ch l)))))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass multiple sequences to `map` it steps through each of them in lock step calling the mapped function with the value from the current position in each. Stopping when one of the sequences runs out.

```
user> (map vector (range 5) (cycle ["A" "B"]))
([0 "A"] [1 "B"] [2 "A"] [3 "B"] [4 "A"])
```

In this case the sequence from `(cycle ["A" "B"])` will keep producing As and Bs forever though map will stop consuming them when the sequence from `(range 5)` ends. each step then calls the vector function with these two arguments and adds the result to the output sequence.

and for the second example using a go-loop is a fairly standard way of fanning out an input sequence:

```
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :refer [go go-loop <! <!! >!! >! chan close!]])
nil
user> (defn fanout [channels file-lines]
        (go-loop [[ch & chans] (cycle channels)
                  [line & lines] file-lines]
          (if line
            (do
              (>! ch line)
              (recur chans lines))
            (doseq [c channels]
              (close! c)))))
#'user/fanout
user> (def lines ["first" "second" "third" "fourth" "fifth"])
#'user/lines
user> (def test-chans [(chan) (chan) (chan)])  
#'user/test-chans
user> (fanout test-chans lines)
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@3b363fc5>
user> (map <!! test-chans)
("first" "second" "third")
user> (map <!! test-chans)
("fourth" "fifth" nil)
```

Comment: So, I'll have to take the result of that, and then doseq over it to put it into channels?

Comment: yes. In my personal opinion I like to keep data generation in it's own function so I can test it independently from the mechanism that is moving it around.

Comment: Yeah, eventually I want to keep all my functions pure and have a layer over it that will manage pushing and pulling from channels, so this works.

Comment: just keep in mind that you can't put the channel operations `<!` etc. into the mapped function because go blocks can't cross function boundaries

Comment: Uh, right. Also, if you look at my practical example, the lines will come from calling `(line-seq rdr)`, where as in here, we have all the data in a single value. Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: `loop`/`recur` instead of `doseq` should be close to what you have. i'll work out an example this afternoon

Comment: Excellent example, thanks. I was using `line-seq` since it's a huge file. This solution will not be lazy, right?

Comment: because the channels are blocking, and line-seq is the input to this then it *wil* be lazy. lines will be read from the file as they are consumed from the channels.